# RubyGem version error: activesupport(1.4.4 not = 3.0.0.beta) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to use the last version of rails, in my Gemfile: `gem 'rails', '3.0.0.beta3'`

When trying to start my server I get this error, do you know how I can fix this issue?

```
$rails s
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: activesupport(1.4.4 not = 3.0.0.beta) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

bundle install return `Your bundle is complete!`

gem list give me

```
activesupport (3.0.0.beta3, 2.3.5, 2.2.2, 1.4.4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so you have activesupport 3.0.0.beta3 while it requires activesupport 3.0.0.beta. Try this:

```
gem install activesupport -v 3.0.0.beta --pre
```

Comment: Thanks, of course..., did the same for actionpack and railties, but now I have this error, /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:334:in `bin_path': can't find executable rails for railties-3.0.0.beta3 (Gem::Exception)
 from /usr/bin/rails:19

Comment: OK i guess this is what needs to be done. Uninstall railties-3.0.0.beta3 gem by doing a gem uninstall. This is because it depends on activesupport 3.0.0.beta3 but your rails install is just beta and not beta3. I guess there is something wrong with your rails install itself. Did you choose the correct version? Because rails 3.0.0.beta3 needs activesupport 3.0.0.beta3. If it asked you for just the beta of activesupport then you never installed rails 3.0.0.beta3 in the first place.